# how to click an image from the screen by using Sikuli with java when there are two exact identical images present in the screen

Tags: java, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I have 2 exact same images (pattern, color, size ,everything is same) on the screen and in this case how do I click on *Image 1*?

Whenever I am using the `s.click()` function, Sikuli tries to click on *Image 1* some times and sometimes on *Image 2*.

I have tried `Pattern` and `exists` but they are also not working as expected.

```
Pattern imagePatternPath = new Pattern("Image.png").exact();
        screen.click(imagePatternPath);
```

I expect to click on *Image 1*, but the actual output is sometime it clicks on *Image 1* and sometimes on *Image 2*.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two absolutely similar patterns on the screen, there is no way for Sikuli to distinguish them without some help. You have few options to resolve this problem.

**location on the screen**

If the patterns appear in known areas on the screen, you can limit the search to the expected area and thus, avoid picking the wrong pattern.

**search by proximity**

If you have any other objects that appear only next to one of the patterns you are attempting to locate but not the other, you can use them as pivots.

Have a look into Sikuli code, especially into the `Region` class here. It exposes various options to modify the search area around found patterns. For example:

```
public Region grow(int range) {
    return grow(range, range);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the patch notes next time, they are very helpful. But here is what I would try:

```
 result = findAll("Image.png")
```

This will return a List which you can iterate through to click the item you wat so in this case you would click the first item.